# Help with Simplying and equation

Tags: inequality

I would like some help simplifying and equation.

Contraints

- $C_1 $ is a positive integer Constant
- $C$ is also a positive integer Constant
- $x$ and $ y $ are both real real numbers. $x\leq 0$, $y\geq 0$

The equation is $(-xC_1)(yC_1)= C$.

When I simplified this equation it looked like this
${C_1}^2(-xy)=C$.
$$(-xy)=\frac{C}{C_1^2}$$

but when I put in some value to test it doesn't seem to be correct,
for example

$C_1=5$

$C=25$

That would leave me with

$$(-xy)=\frac{25}{5^2}
$$

$(-xy)=1$

Comment: OP: I've edited it for appearance; can you verify this is what you intend?

Comment: Assuming that I haven't changed anything substantive, what is the problem with your result?  It seems reasonable.  If $X = -1, Y = 1$, then you have (from the original equation) $(-(-1) \times 5)(1 \times 5) = (5)(5) = 25$.

Comment: Thanks Brian, Yes that is what i Intended.

Comment: And what is the problem with the conclusion that $(-xy)=1$?

Comment: well i wanted to make sure tthe reduction correct and it doesnt seem to make sense that a negative number * a positive Number would  =1 when you your not dealing with imaginary numbers

Comment: if you start with a number like 63 which is a composite of 9 and 7 which equals 63  then i dont see how you can get that our of the equation -xy=1.

Comment: @user324976: But it isn't a negative number times a positive number; it's minus a negative number (i.e., a positive number) times a positive number.  Remember that by your own conditions, $x$ is a negative number, so $-x$ is positive, so $-xy$ is also positive.